# the application requires one of the following versions of the .net framework. how to solve this for github?

Tags: github, push

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9L6E.png)

when i am trying to push any project to github this error shows. Can anybody help?

Comment: have you tried to install the version of .NET the image advices you to install?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take[the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your source code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're trying to use Git Credential Manager Core, which is a credential helper that's commonly installed on Windows.  This program is written in C#, which means that you need to have .NET installed.

You have a couple options in this case:

- Install .NET as prompted.
- Change to a different credential helper by running `git config --unset-all credential.helper && git config credential.helper wincred` (which would change you to `wincred`.  When prompted for your username, enter it, and then when prompted for your password, enter a new personal access token.
- Switch to SSH by using `git remote set-url origin SSH-URL`, where `SSH-URL` is the SSH version of your URL.  If you haven't generated an SSH key and uploaded the public portion to GitHub, you'll need to do that.